# Cant keep session in some sites with wifi antenna

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection

I have a wifi antenna p2p connection with a router to connect with the server (ppp). Then I have another wifi router that connect with the first one with lan. Then I connect my notebook with the second with wifi.
I used to have another server that didnt use ppp and I didnt have any trouble with my internet. Now with this new one I cant access sites that have session/cookie like gmail or facebook. On windows the internet works fine, but on ubuntu and my android keep loading until expires.
I tried one time use "# dhclient -r; dhclient". It worked, but now I tried again and nothing. I have no idea what I can do.